# Question about quantum gravity and super-fluid vacuum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity, loop-quantum-gravity

I've been reading a lot about super-fluid vacuum/quantum foam/quantum vacuum etc and how quantum gravity (as hypothesized) will emerge out of interaction of these virtual particles that make up said vacuum. Further, they used some form of Navier-Stokes equation with time averaged viscosity taken as zero and to arrive at force density similar to force of gravity. So far i have not found any article with any end result; most are just arguments.

Would like to know what articles you think put it out most logically?